# AVR + Hi-Fi speakers?

Tags: audio, television, speakers, music, sound-system

I'm moving into a new home and I'd like to buy a TV and a sound system for the living room. I'd like to use my sound system to:

1. Listen to music (say, playing from my phone via bluetooth)
2. Use with the TV.

I know very little about sound systems, but I understand that a hi-fi system (stereo amp + hi-fi speakers) is different from a home theater system (AVR + a bunch of different speakers). I don't much care about the "surround" experience though, especially since the living room is small. I'd just like a decent sound system to play music and I figure I could use it for the TV too, sparing me the expense of a sound bar.

I'm considering the following setup: AVR + bookshelf (or tower) speakers. Let's say my budget is $1000 max, what about:

1. [Yamaha TSR-700 AVR](https://www.ebay.com/itm/133824575283?epid=7041854842&LH_ItemCondition=2000)
2. [Triangle Borea BR03](https://www.ebay.com/itm/283935407707) bookshelf speakers (or [Sony SSCS3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07147TBD5) tower speakers)

Does a setup like this make sense to you? I guess one question is, will this AVR do a good job with my stereo speakers. Any other tips/advice to consider? In case it matters, the TV will probably be an [LG C1](https://www.lg.com/us/tvs/lg-oled65c1pub-oled-4k-tv). Many thanks!

[Small additional question: I've noticed that a couple of high-end amps/AVRs such as the [NAD T778](https://www.crutchfield.com/S-YqGfKBDfpS3/p_745M10/NAD-Masters-Series-M10.html) or the [Cambridge Evo](https://www.crutchfield.com/p_779EVO75/Cambridge-Audio-Evo-75.html) include a nice display screen. That's pretty cool. Why don't more amps/avrs include this instead of their ugly 80s-like screen?]

Comment: Sorry, but hi-Fi is off-topic here [in fact there's nowhere on Stack Exchange for HiFi questions]. See https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic. You need somewhere like https://www.avforums.com

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to go for Cerwin-Vega XLS-28 [tower speakers](https://thebestronics.com/tower-speakers/), as they sounds good with TV and require less space. You can also read buying guide in detail at [thebestronics](https://thebestronics.com/)